# Storing Setting Information

Tags: java, xml, spring, jakarta-ee

I am developing a web application and this web application is to be sold to many people. The application is being developed in Java Spring. The application has a database and when sold this database could be on different locations.

Where is the best way to store this database location so the Java code can find the database?

I would store it in a XML file but where would it go, so that the database location can be changed easily by someone.

I don't want to store it in the Spring Beans. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's a web application, which suggests that you'll give them a WAR file.  All the Spring configuration and properties will be packaged; changing something will mean opening the package, which you don't want them to do.

You should set up database access using JNDI names, which are set on the app server the package is deployed to.  Give instructions to show how to set one up for Tomcat and other app servers.  When your app starts, it'll get the data source name from the app server.

You're assuming that they'll be sophisticated enough to be able to create a JNDI data source on their app server or that your documentation is good enough.  Good luck with that.

Another thought would be for you to create a small in memory database like Hypersonic or Derby that comes with configuration information for your app.  Tell users to put it in a location outside the app that you specify (e.g. c:/yourApp/configuration), provide a script to start it up when the app starts, and let your application query for database connection information when it loads.

Now you'll be counting on them knowing how to create INSERT or UPDATE queries for your in-memory database.  But your chances of writing documentation to instruct how to do it are better, because you don't have to figure out how to do it for WebLogic, Tomcat, Jetty, JBOSS, WebSphere, Glassfish, and every other Java EE app server.

Comment: Mmm, the web app itself can expose the internal config db via an admin interface.

Comment: True enough, but I'd want to restrict access to that URL to admins only.  Don't let users have at it.   But a very good thought, indeed.

Comment: You just configure the DB to restrict access so only admins can configure the DB. Admins are configured in the DB. Oh, wait.

Comment: I'd prefer that you accept the answer.  Your manners are wonderful, but questioners are supposed to accept answers that help.  It's good for me and for you.